# Remove php file extension

Tags: .htaccess

I am trying to implement url this way  localhost/mysite/contact/  without php extension and adding a trailing slash at the end but it is not working.

This is the code sample:

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/$ $1.php
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/$ /$1/$2.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(\.[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,5}|/)$
RewriteRule (.*)$ /$1/ [R=301,L]
```

How can I implement the following: 
localhost/mysite/page/
Any help please?
Thank you.

Comment: Is your PHP accessed as `http://localhost/mysite/contact.php` ?

Comment: That is right. It is http://localhost/mysite/contact.php

Answer (score 0):

Enable `mod_rewrite` and `.htaccess` through `httpd.conf` and then put this code in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /mysite/

RewriteRule ^foo/?$ bar [L,NC,R]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/mysite/$1.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ $1.php [L]
```

Comment: So what happens when you enter: `http://localhost/mysite/contact` ? Do you get a 404? Also is this in `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` OR `DOCUMENT_ROOT/mysite/.htaccess`?

Comment: Object not found!

The requested URL was not found on this server. If you entered the URL manually please check your spelling and try again.

If you think this is a server error, please contact the webmaster.
Error 404
localhost
Apache/2.4.3 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.0.1c PHP/5.4.7

Comment: `Is this in DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess OR DOCUMENT_ROOT/mysite/.htaccess`?

Comment: the .htaccess is in /mysite/.htaccess  folder

Comment: This is that I have done. I know that working with .htaccess is hard.

Comment: Have you added `RewriteRule ^foo/?$ bar [L,NC,R]` this line also in your `mysite/.htaccess` ?

Comment: In that case I think your .htaccess is not enabled. Try putting some garbage text on top of this .htaccess and see if you get 500 error or not.

Comment: ok sure, but most of online resources on this are pretty confusing.

Answer (score 0):

Ensure you have mod rewrite enabled and loaded

Eg
RewriteEngine on

this will work without the file v system checking overhead

RewriteRule ^([^.?]+)$ %{REQUEST_URI}.php [L]

Comment: Full code:
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /mysite/
RewriteRule ^([^.?]+)$ %{REQUEST_URI}.php [L]
</IfModule>

Comment: I have got the same redirect problem!!